# Jquery to update below CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please help, I need to update background color attribute from “background:#000;”  to “background:#25981B; or any color, green , blue etc in the stylesheet using JQuery”

Thanks here I'm trying to achive rounded corner on top of rectangle dynamically using JQUERY..  Please check the the URL, In the example how can we now change the top black color to green or any thing eles... 
http://jsfiddle.net/samansari/cD4kf/

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Thanks,
SAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ComboZhc/3Jntr/)

```
$('div').css('background-color', '#981B1B');
$('b.r1').css('background-color', '#981B1B');
$('b.r2').css('background-color', '#981B1B');
$('b.r3').css('background-color', '#981B1B');
$('b.r4').css('background-color', '#981B1B');
```

​
It is not beautiful, but it works.

```
$('div').css('background-color', '#981B1B');
$('b').css('background-color', '#981B1B');​
```

This is a more beautiful way to do this.

Edit: Ooops, I made a little mistake. JsFiddle is updated, and a nice solution is:

```
$('div').css('background-color', '#bcd');
$('b.rtop b').css('background-color', '#bcd');​
```

Comment: HI combozhc, Thank u very much for this solution, The above 5 lines solution works but not below 2 lines, can you please check it..  finally ur the best...

Comment: $('div').css('background-color', '#bcd');
$('b.rtop b').css('background-color', '#bcd');​

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/RYwv5/)**

```
$('.rtop').closest('div').css('background-color', '#981B1B')
```

Updated as per comments by OP

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/cD4kf/17/)

Comment: HI Adil, This is close to solution but who can i make the rest TOP portion also have same color #981B1B, Which is currently black color, to achive rounded corner dynamically using JQUERY..

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I got busy and you did not responded to previous reply anyhow you got the solution that is good.